# Spark on Yarn Client Mode - HADOOP_CONF_DIR is ignored

Tags: apache-spark

I have Spark 2.1.1 installed on top of Hadoop 2.8.1.

I have already specified HADOOP_CONF_DIR on spark-env.sh. I also have the following setting on spark-defaults.sh

```
spark.yarn.access.namenodes   hdfs://hadoop-node0:55555/
```

But when I execute spark-shell with the following command for instance,

```
sparkuser@hadoop-node0:/home/apps/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7$ bin/spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client
```

HADOOP_CONF_DIR setting seems to be ignored so it does not retrieve the settings on core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml, as I always get the following error:

```
17/07/25 10:15:24 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: spark
```

When I added "spark" on my /etc/hosts as alternative for localhost, I always get the following error:

```
17/07/25 10:17:15 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.ConnectException: Call From XXXX/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX to spark:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

So it always tries to reach 127.0.0.1:8020 which of course does not work as nothing is listening on it.

What do you think I missed specifying in the config files?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Kind regards,

Anto

Comment: Curious, I run into a similar issue this morning. In my case, despite `yarn-site.xml` contains `yarn.resourcemanager.address` with proper value, and `YARN_CONF_DIR` has been properly set up, `spark-submit` only tries to connect to `0.0.0.0:8032`, where nothing is listening. I'll track this question.

Comment: Anyway, in your case the connection attempts should be to `8032` or `8050` port, which are typical YARN resource manager ports. `8020` is the inter-process communications port for Hadoop's HDFS. Maybe Spark is indeed reading your configuration, but it is not ok ;)

Comment: Thanks frb. I am not sure from where Spark gets port 8020. I have not specified anything that is using that port. The only parameter related to IPC that I set is `dfs.datanode.ipc.address` on hdfs-site.xml. I set that to listen on port 57222.

Comment: Just tried to downgrade Hadoop to version 2.7.3, but still get exactly the same problem. Perhaps there is something wrong on my config files, but I am not sure which part is related to the request to Resource Manager on `spark:8020` or `127.0.0.1:8020`. I have specified almost all `dfs.*.*.address` on non-default ports. Any hints please?

Comment: I finally fixed it, it was a problem with `YARN_CONF_DIR`, which as its names specifies, must point to a directory, not to a file as I was doing :) Now it works. I'll put an answer detailing this.

Comment: Thanks frb. I actually have `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop` and `export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_CONF_DIR`on `hadoop-env.sh`, `spark-env.sh` and `.bashrc`, but I still get the same problem.